# Does 2000 Mercury Sable LS Premium have 12V available?

Tags: electrical, mercury, sable

I'm going to be driving/living in a '00 Mercury Sable Sedan LS Premium 4D, which has a 24V electrical system.  100% of my equipment runs on 12V.  Does this car have a high-current (>40A) 12V regulator in it to power my gear?  Or will I have to build/buy my own?

Comment: What make you think that the car has a 24V electrical system? I'm not aware of any US made cars that have 24V systems.

Comment: It specifies on the side of the car that it is 24V.  Also, Kelly Blue Book confirms.

Comment: That would be the 24 valve double over head camshaft 3.0 liter V6. You have a 12 volt electrical system not a 24 volt system. Your engine has 24 valves, that's what the 24V means when listed under engine.

Comment: @vini_i - Just a reminder to put your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vehicle is equipped with the Duratec 24 valve double over head cam 3.0 liter V6. In the descriptions where you see 24V, that stand for 24 valve. The car has a 12 volt electrical system and not a 24 volt one.

The Mercury Sable has 2 different engine options. One is a 3.0 liter V6 overhead valve (OHV) 12 valve and the other is 3.0 liter V6 double overhead cam (DOHC) 24 valve. The 24V is there to distinguish the engines because they are both 3.0 liter V6.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm headed on to be an Electrical Engineer, so where I see #V I think volts instinctively.  Any idea how powerful the alternator on this beast is (200hp engine)?

Answer (score 1):

You only find 24volt vehicle systems in military vehicles/emergency vehicles. I don't think Mercury would release a vehicle that required 100% different electronics amongst it's line of vehicle. Whats the point?

24volt vehicles are that way to power on board equipment.

I.E. Military Communications vehicle.